# Spaces, Apostrophe, and Ampersand in MySQL Enum Values

Tags: mysql

I am creating a MySQL Table, and one of column's type is `ENUM`.

I have several different `ENUM` values. Some of them are two or more words, e.g. Hugo Boss.

Other `ENUM` values have an apostrophe in them, e.g. Men's, or other characters, e.g. &.

My question is two part:

1. It is ok to have one or more spaces in an `ENUM` value (two words, or more)?
2. Are apostrophes, ampersands, and other such characters, allowed in `ENUM` values? And if they are, how would I go about placing them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems so:

```
MySQL [files]> create temporary table t(foo ENUM('123', '1&2', '3\'4'));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.17 sec)

MySQL [files]> show create table t\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: t
Create Table: CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `t` (
  `foo` enum('123','1&2','3''4') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
1 row in set (0.09 sec)

MySQL [files]> insert into t values (0), (1), (2), (3);
Query OK, 4 rows affected, 1 warning (0.12 sec)
Records: 4  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

MySQL [files]> show warnings;
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                  |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1265 | Data truncated for column 'foo' at row 1 |
+---------+------+------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.11 sec)

MySQL [files]> select * from t;
+------+
| foo  |
+------+
|      |
| 123  |
| 1&2  |
| 3'4  |
+------+
4 rows in set (0.09 sec)

MySQL [files]>
```

Note: The warning means that I have used a value which was not allowed - I tried to insert 3, which is not defined as value for the `ENUM`.

So it works perfectly - as with any other strings in MySQL. You only have to take care that you treat them correctly - either as hex values, or use `mysql_real_escape_string()` or prepared statements. This provides for correct communication of "critical" values such as `\\`, `'`, `"` etc.

For example, if I have a string which contains "3'4", and I want to define it as a part of an enum, I create the query by putting one of `0x332734` or `'3\'4'` to the appropriate place. `'3\'4'` is obtained as a result of `mysql_real_escape_string("3'4")` in the used programming language.

NUL characters are not allowed as `ENUM` components as they would be in data strings - the used string is terminated before, though.